# Lumer-Phillips Theorem for non-contraction semigroups?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Let $H$ be a closed operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$. The Lumer-Phillips theorem states that $H$ is a generator of a one-parameter contraction semigroup if and only if

$\Re\langle H\psi,\psi\rangle\leq 0$ for all $\psi\in\mathcal H$ and

there exists at most one $z$ in $\rho(H)$ with $\Re z>0$.

In particular, the numerical range of $H$ plays an important role in determining wether $H$ generates a contraction semigroup. My question:
Does there exist a theorem relating the numerical range of an operator to it being a generator of an *arbitrary* bounded semigroup (not necessarily one of contractions)?

Comment: You can renorm so that it is contractive, but that may only end up being a Banach space norm, and not generated by an inner product. If $T$ is a bounded $C^0$ semigroup, then $\|x\|_T = \sup_{t \ge 0}\|T(t)x\|$ is an equivalent norm with respect to which $T$ is a contractive $C^0$ semigroup.

Comment: It's not so much the numerical range that counts, but rather the strength of the singularity in the resolvent as you approach the imaginary axis. Generators have square roots because the semigroup integral definitions exist due to the resolvent having no worse that $1/\lambda$ behavior near the imaginary axis. That, by the way, will not hold if you have nilpotent components, and nilpotent matrices don't have square roots. So this resolvent bound is more critical than just numerical range.